# Protractor check for location path

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, automation, protractor

Is it possible to check the location path? I'm new to AngularJS and I'm learning with a book that describes ngScenario. This package is deprecated and I'm trying to update the described test to protractor.

E.g.

```
expect(browser().location().path()).toEqual('/books');
```

becomes:

```
expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('http://localhost:8080/#/books');
```

But I'd like to avoid `http://localhost:8080/`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use the power of *jasmine matchers*:

```
expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch(/\/#\/books$/);  // /#/books at the end of url
expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEndWith("/#/books");
expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain("/#/books");
```

<sub>where [`toEndWith()`](https://github.com/JamieMason/Jasmine-Matchers#toendwith) is coming from an awesome `jasmine-matchers` library.</sub>

Or, if you want an exact match, get the base URL:

```
expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual(browser.baseUrl + "/#/books");
```

Comment: `expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual(browser.baseUrl + "#/books");` works but I don't know, how to use jasmine matchers with protractor.

Comment: I had to insert `onPrepare: function(){
    require("jasmine-expect");
  }` into my protractor conf. Now botch variants work.

Answer (score 0):

The getCurrentUrl() function does not return the whole baseUrl (which is http://localhost:8080/#/books).
So, you can try it:

```
browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
    return /#\/books/.test(url);
});
```

"test" is a function of the regex module. In the example above, the text "#/books" is being compared to the current url